# Why "adb remount" retruns "remount failed" on Android emulator?

Tags: adb, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio. I was trying to set up dev environment and it requires to modify `hosts` file. So,

1. I created new devices in ADM (Nexus 4, Android 10 x86_64 without Google API and without Google Play).
2. I lunched the emulator
3. Then I tried following instructions from [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47622017/1153296). I'm using Linux Mint so:

```
$ ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/.adb root

output: 
restarting adbd as root
```

Okay, I got root:

```
$ ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/.adb shell whoami

output: 
root
```

Then I suppose to remount and this is where I stuck:

```
 ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/.adb remount

output: 
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
avb_ops_user.cpp:217: ERROR: Error writing data.
avb_user_verity.c:205: ERROR: Error writing to partition 'vbmeta'
E Skipping /system
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
W DM_DEV_STATUS failed for scratch: No such device or address
E [liblp]No device named scratch
[liblp]Partition scratch will resize from 0 bytes to 814587904 bytes
E [liblp]bool android::fs_mgr::WritePrimaryMetadata(int, const android::fs_mgr::LpMetadata &, uint32_t, const std::string &, const std::function<bool (int, const std::string &)> &) write 540 bytes failed: Operation not permitted
E [libfs_mgr]add partition scratch
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
W DM_DEV_STATUS failed for scratch: No such device or address
E Can not mount overlayfs for partitions: No such file or directory
Skip mounting partition: /product
Skip mounting partition: /product_services
E failed to remount partition dev:/dev/block/dm-1 mnt:/vendor: Read-only file system
E Consider providing all the dependencies to enable overlayfs
/system/bin/remount exited with status 10
remount failed
```

I don't know if `remount` is the critical issue, but i guess so. At the moment I don't have permission to modify `/etc/`. For example:

```
$ ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools./adb shell "cp /etc/hosts /etc/hosts.bak"

output: 
cp: /etc/hosts.bak: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run Android Emulator with `--writable-system` commandline option in order to temporarily disable `dm-verity`. Then you can run `adb remount`.

Comment: ... like the answer Yevgen has linked in question already does

Comment: @alecxs yes. And the question is off-topic here in my opinion.

Comment: It's `-writable-system` https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline#startup-options